# Create UEFI partition using VDS

Tags: c#-4.0, wmi, vds, uefi

I'm trying to create UEFI partition using the [`IVdsCreatePartitionEx::CreatePartitionEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vds/nf-vds-ivdscreatepartitionex-createpartitionex) method.

In the [`CREATE_PARTITION_PARAMETERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vds/ns-vds-create_partition_parameters) struct parameter I passed `PARTITION_SYSTEM_GUID` (c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b) as the `partitionType` and `GPT_BASIC_DATA_ATTRIBUTE_NO_DRIVE_LETTER` (0x8000000000000000) as the attributes.

But I get an unknown partition with type c12a0000-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b.

[image: Screenshot of DISKPART showing error]
.

Any ideas what can be wrong here?

Also I tried to create UEFI partition using WMI on Win8.
But I got Error Value 41010 - The specified partition type is not valid.
Here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\Root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage");
        scope.Connect();

        const string query = "SELECT * FROM MSFT_Disk WHERE Number = 7";
        var objectQuery = new ObjectQuery(query);
        var seacher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objectQuery);
        var disks = seacher.Get();

        var disk = disks.Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (disk == null)
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException("Disk is null");
        }

        var parameters = disk.GetMethodParameters("CreatePartition");
        FillInvocationParameters(parameters, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Size", 104857600 }, { "Offset", 5ul * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }, { "Alignment", 512 }, { "AssignDriveLetter", false }, { "GptType", "c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b" }, { "IsHidden", false } });

        var result = disk.InvokeMethod("CreatePartition", parameters, null);
        var returnValue = result["ReturnValue"];
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.Fail(exception.Message);
    }
}
static void FillInvocationParameters(ManagementBaseObject invokeParameters, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    foreach (var pair in parameters)
    {
        string stringParamValue;

        var managementObjectParam = pair.Value as ManagementObject;
        var arrayParam = pair.Value as string[];

        if (managementObjectParam != null)
        {
            stringParamValue = managementObjectParam.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);
            invokeParameters[pair.Key] = stringParamValue;
        }
        else if (arrayParam != null)
        {
            invokeParameters[pair.Key] = arrayParam;
        }
        else if (pair.Value != null)
        {
            stringParamValue = pair.Value.ToString();
            invokeParameters[pair.Key] = stringParamValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see the snippet of code where you make this call and the raw error itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem using VDS: I created volume using IVdsPack::CreateVolume(), received it's partition, formatted it to Fat32 using IVdsAdvancedDisk::FormatPartition() and 
changed PartitionType using IVdsAdvancedDisk2::ChangePartitionType()